# r.mapcalc - Python script in GRASS

Tags: python, grass-gis, error, r.mapcalc

I'm having trouble with a simple script in Python. I do not know where the error is. I use GRASS 8.0.

```
import os

import math

import grass.script as grass

elevation = 'dem_10_fill'
elev_new = 'elevation_mod'

grass.run_command('g.region', raster=elevation)
grass.mapcalc('elev_new = if(elevation < 280, elevation)')
```

The message is:

```
Niewłaściwa mapa elevation / Incorrect elevation map
Parse error
ERROR: parse error
ERROR: An error occurred while running r.mapcalc with expression: elev_new = if(elevation < 280, elevation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names that you defined are not parsed inside your expression string. You need to build the mapcalc expression using python string formatting.
i.e.:

```
expr = '{0} = if({1} < 280, {1})'.format(elev_new, elevation)
grass.mapcalc(expr)
```